# pigscript error not calculating max

Tags: max, apache-pig

I'm having an issue with a pig script, I've tried a lot of different ways. Can anyone point out what exactly I'm doing wrong? It should be pretty straight forwards, I'm trying to get the max after calculating the average.

```
 a = LOAD 'default.books' using org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
b = LOAD 'default.book_rating' using org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader(); 

books_and_ratings = join a by isbn, b by isbn; 

by_isbn = GROUP books_and_ratings BY (a::isbn);

DESCRIBE by_isbn;

average_book_rating = FOREACH by_isbn 
        GENERATE books_and_ratings.book_title, books_and_ratings.a::isbn as isbn1,
        books_and_ratings.book_author, books_and_ratings.publisher,
        AVG(books_and_ratings.book_rating) as AVG_RATING;

DESCRIBE average_book_rating;

group_avg = GROUP average_book_rating ALL;

DESCRIBE group_avg;

max_avg_rating = FOREACH group_avg 
    GENERATE FLATTEN average_book_rating.a::book_title, isbn1,
             average_book_rating.a::book_author, average_book_rating.a::publisher, MAX(AVG_RATING);

dump max_avg_rating;
```

Failed to parse:   mismatched input 'average_book_rating' expecting LEFT_PAREN

Comment: Are you getting an error, or is it just not calculating the max properly?

Comment: @eyal getting an error actually....

Comment: The last stmt calculating the max_avg_rating is not correct. Can you paste the exact error?

Comment: If you're trying to get the maximum of the average ratings, it looks like Sivasakthi has suggested a solution that will work. Or are you trying to get something else?

Comment: @eyal yeah, well there can be multiple books with highest average rating

Comment: @Eyal have a look please

Answer (score 2):

Can you try like this.

```
max_avg_rating  = ORDER average_book_rating BY AVG_RATING DESC;  
top_most_rating = LIMIT max_avg_rating 1;  
dump top_most_rating;
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing Hades latest comment ("there can be multiple books with highest average rating"), I think you need another grouping, after the first one, which groups the ratings by isbn to get what you want.

Start with something like this:

> grouped_rating = GROUP average_book_rating by AVG_RATING;

Then you can use code like @Sivasakthi's:

> ordered_avg_rating  = ORDER grouped_rating BY group DESC;
>   top_most_rating = LIMIT ordered_avg_rating 1;
>   dump top_most_rating;

This way, if there are multiple results with an equal, highest rating, *top_most_rating* will have a bag of all the information for the books that received this highest rating. Of course, you can project this to get something more convenient if you don't want it as a bag.

**UPDATE:**

Here's how I would change your code above. One thing which isn't purely functional is that I would average the ratings first, and only then join the book/author information - this will be better performance wise, because otherwise you're increasing the size of the ratings (of which there are many) when going over them.

So it looks like this:

```
    -- assume a: book_title, isbn, book_author, publisher (and maybe more, which we'll ignore)
    a = LOAD 'default.books' using org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();

    -- assume b: isbn, book_rating (and maybe more, which we'll ignore)
    b = LOAD 'default.book_rating' using org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();

    by_isbn = GROUP b BY isbn;

    average_book_rating = FOREACH by_isbn GENERATE AVG(b.book_rating) AS AVG_RATING, group AS isbn;

    group_avg = GROUP average_book_rating BY AVG_RATING;

    ordered_avg_rating = ORDER group_avg BY group DESC;

    top_most_rating = LIMIT ordered_avg_rating 1;

    b = FOREACH top_most_rating GENERATE flatten(average_book_rating);

    -- now add the book information

    books_and_ratings = JOIN a BY isbn, b BY isbn;

    books_and_ratings = FOREACH books_and_ratings GENERATE a::book_title AS title, a::isbn AS isbn, a::book_author AS author,a::publisher AS publisher, b::average_book_rating::AVG_RATING AS max_rating;
```

Hope this works out for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i edited my question...can you have a look and see whats wrong with it?

Comment: In the code you edited (in your original description) you grouped by ALL, instead of by AVG_RATING as in my answer. That means all the rows will be grouped into a single bag. I'm still not sure what you're trying to do, but FLATTEN uses parentheses, and that's the immediate reason for the error you got. The code in my answer will indeed get you a bag of all the books that got the single highest average rating.